# How can I view gzipped files in less without having to type zless?

Tags: less, compression

I am using Ubuntu, and I would like to be able to type `less compressed_text_file.gz` and page the contents of the text file in uncompressed form. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: +1 for introducing me to zless

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can configure the key bindings and set many [settings](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/less.1.html#contenttoc12) for `less` in a file called `~/.lesskey`. Once you've created the file, run the [`lesskey` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/lesskey.1.html); it generates a file called `~/.less` which `less` reads when it starts.

The setting you want is [`LESSOPEN`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/less.1.html#contenttoc7). It's an input formatter for less. The `less` package comes with a sample formatter in `/bin/lesspipe`; it decompresses gzipped files, shows content listings for many multi-file archive formats, and converts several formatted texts formats to plain text. In your `~/.lesskey`:

```
#env
LESSOPEN=|/bin/lesspipe %s
```

Comment: This is the answer that actually solves the question: how to not have to type the `z` in `zless` - automatically uncompressing rather than having to remember to add the `z`

Comment: On Redhat based distributions, `less` can open compressed files, and i see no `.lesskey` or no alias or no specials parameters to the command

Comment: @AlexF [It's done with environment variables](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62655/less-doesnt-automatically-decompress-gzipped-files#comment1408799_62660). `/etc/lesskey` would be another possibility.

Answer (score 81):

Use `zcat`, then pipe it to `less`.

```
$ zcat $FILE | less
```

Comment: I would prefer if `less` just worked on compressed files.

Comment: Unlike the accepted answer this one is a clean and unix-way solution. Thanks!

Comment: This is as simple as it gets, win.  One thing to bear in mind is that if you open a large file with less, it opens in a useable way, straight away.  With this approach, it will open but you won't be able to do much (if anything) until the compression has finished running it all through the pipe.  So if you're planning on opening it repeatedly, it's better to decompress it first.  Otherwise, do this and check your emails or something :)

Comment: A silly question gets a silly top answer: why not just use `zless`?

Answer (score 9):

I'm using IBM and when using `zcat`, it will complains that it can't find the file ending with `.Z`.

On IBM one can use `gzcat`:

```
$ gzcat log_file.gz | less
```

Comment: What do you mean by "using IBM"? Do you mean AIX?

Comment: Using `gzcat` is also necessary on Solaris 5

Comment: The solution also works on MacOS