# How do I view cp1251 text file in UTF-8 console?

Tags: console, character-encoding, less, text

Attempt 1:

```
$ less subs.srt
"subs.srt" may be a binary file.  See it anyway? 
<C8><F2><E0><EB><FC><FF><ED> ...
```

Attempt 2:

```
$ LANG=ru_RU.CP1251 less subs.srt
����� �����, ��� ������.
��� ������� �������������! ...
```

Workaround:

```
$ iconv -f cp1251 < subs.srt | less
```

How do I do it conveniently?

Comment: What do you mean by “conveniantly”?

Comment: By "conveniently" I mean: 1. Avoiding typing long command lines; 2. Avoiding holding entire file in memory; 3. Accepting `less`'s options on command line in regular way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make `less` run in a different encoding from the terminal's, use [luit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luit) (which ships with the X11 utility suite).

```
LANG=ru_RU.CP1251 luit less subs.srt
```

If you want to detect the encoding automatically, that's trickier, because a text file carries no indication of its encoding. 
The software [Enca](http://cihar.com/software/enca/) tries to recognize the encoding of a file based on its language:

```
$ enca -L russian subs.srt
MS-Windows code page 1251
$ iconv -f "$(enca -iL russian subs.srt)" | less
```

You can make this combination a `LESSOPEN` filter (see [How can I view gzipped files in less without having to type zless?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12383/how-can-i-view-gzipped-files-in-less-without-having-to-type-zless/12385#12385) for an example). That may not give good results for text that isn't actually in Russian however.

If you only use UTF-8 and CP1251, you can fall back to CP1251 when a file [isn't valid UTF-8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6516/filtering-invalid-utf8) — there are “holes” in UTF-8 which cause most files in an 8-bit encoding not to be valid UTF-8. Proof-of-concept filter script for `LESSOPEN` (might not work on systems other than Linux, because it relies on `head -c N` reading exactly N bytes):

```
#!/bin/sh
head=$(head -c 1000)
if printf '%s\n' "$head" | grep -qav '^.*$'; then
  { printf '%s\n' "$head"; cat; } | iconv -f CP1251
else
  { printf '%s\n' "$head"; cat; }
fi
```